# why is my else if statement not setting loopCount to 0 when START is pressed a second time

Tags: c

Im trying to set loopCount = 1 when i press START once, if pressed again I want loopCount = 0. Help would be appreciated.
here is the code

```c
int frameCount = 0;
int loopCount = 0;
int buttonPressed = 0;
int backwardCount = 1;
void updateGame() {
    if (BUTTON_PRESSED(BUTTON_START)) {
        loopCount = 1;
    }
    else if (BUTTON_PRESSED(BUTTON_START) && loopCount == 1) {
        loopCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `else` means?

Answer (score 3):

The first `if` will catch all cases when `BUTTON_PRESSED(BUTTON_START)` is `true`. Since you want to toggle `loopCount` when the button is pressed, combine the two `if`s into one where you just toggle the variable:

```cpp
if (BUTTON_PRESSED(BUTTON_START)) {
    loopCount = !loopCount;
}
```

Comment: Or if assigning to `1` is really wanted, `loopCount ? 0 : 1`.

Comment: @konsolebox Yes, or `loopCount = 1 - loopCount;`. The variable should probably be renamed (since it's not much of a counter) and be made into a `bool` though.

Answer (score 0):

Write your program as

```
int frameCount = 0;
int loopCount = 0;
int buttonPressed = 0;
int backwardCount = 0;
void updateGame() {
    if(BUTTON_PRESSED(BUTTON_START)) {
        if(loopCount == 0) {
            loopCount = 1;
        } else if(loopCount == 1) {
            loopCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```